# Changing the color of a div with a button by using an eventlistener instead of inline onclick or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the background colour of my div with the click of a button.

I have 3 different buttons for 3 different colours. with these buttons I would like to change the colour of my "enemy".

```css
#Enemy {
  border-radius: 25px/25px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200;
  z-index: 2;
  color: blue;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='Enemy'></div>

<div id="EnemyColours">
  <h1>Enemy Colour</h1>
  <button type="button" name="bgcE" value="purple">paars</button>
  <button type="button" name="bgcE" value="brown">bruin</button>
  <button type="button" name="bgcE" value="orange">oranje</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You neglected to post the JavaScript you tried, showing us what part you were stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Using only JavaScript, you just need to attach the `click` event with all buttons, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#EnemyColours button").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("Enemy").style.backgroundColor = this.value;
  });
});
```

It uses `document.querySelectorAll("#EnemyColours button")` to get all buttons, then loop over them and attach a click handler function that uses each button `value` as a `background-color` for the `Enemy` div.

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#EnemyColours button").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("Enemy").style.backgroundColor = this.value;
  });
});
```

```css
#Enemy {
  border-radius: 25px/25px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200;
  z-index: 2;
  color: blue;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='Enemy'>Enemy</div>

<div id="EnemyColours">
  <h1>Enemy Colour</h1>
  <button type="button" name="bgcE" value="purple">paars</button>
  <button type="button" name="bgcE" value="brown">bruin</button>
  <button type="button" name="bgcE" value="orange">oranje</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following, assumed that you want to keep the name of buttons same.

Get all buttons and add event listener to each of them like following.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("bgcE");
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("Enemy").style.backgroundColor = this.value; 
});
}
```

Check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/80m9c6tx/).